# Parallelizing recursion in a for-loop using readdir

Tags: c, parallel-processing, task, openmp

I'd like to parallelize a C-program which recursively calculates the size of a directory and its sub-directories, using OpenMP and C.

My issue is, that when I get into a directory using `opendir`, and I iterate through the sub-directories using `readdir` I can only access them one by one until I've reached the last sub-directory. It all works well sequentially.

When parallelizing the program, however, I think it would make sense to split the number of sub-directories in half (or even smaller partitions) and recurse through the sub-directories using OpenMp Tasks.

Obviously I can't simply split the problem size (= number of sub-directories) in half, because of the structure of the for-loop, and loops like this cannot be parallelized using `#pragma omp for`.

Does anybody have an idea on how to split this function into tasks? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is some of my code (I've removed parts I do not deem relevant for this question.)

```
int calculate_folder_size(const char *path) {

    struct stat sb;

    if (S_ISREG(sb.st_mode)) { // if it's a file, not a directory (base case)
        return sb.st_size;
    }

    DIR *folder = opendir(path);

    struct dirent *element;
    size_t size = 4096;

    for (element = readdir(folder); element != NULL; element = readdir(folder)) {

   //(...)
            if (element->d_type == DT_DIR) {
                // recursive call of calculate_folder_size
                size += calculate_folder_size(name);
            } else {
             //(...)
            }
        }
    }
    closedir(folder);
    return size;
}
```

Comment: Given that the file system is likely to be a tree, and your underlying machine is likely to *not* be a tree, you likely have a fixed amount of parallel computational capacity. Mapping a tree of work onto a fixed set of workers is best done by futures and promises.

Comment: I don't see any use in parallel processing directories as the main bottleneck will be the [disk] I/O. At worst you will decrease performance due to the disk heads seeking and seeking and seeking to satisfy te requests of the parallel threads.

Comment: Thank you two. Considering that afaik the hard drive cannot perform parallel read/write operations it seems like an odd homework assignment that I was given here...

Comment: The hard drive cannot perform reads in parallel, but the filesystem can issue more reads per unit of time when read in parallel than when read sequentially. This is a typical example of a latency hiding technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a modern compiler with support for OpenMP tasks, which removes Visual C++ from the equation. Provided you are using such a compiler, all you need to do is to turn the recursive invocations to `calculate_folder_size()` into OpenMP tasks:

```
int calculate_folder_size(const char *path) {
    struct stat sb;

    if (S_ISREG(sb.st_mode)) { // if it's a file, not a directory (base case)
        return sb.st_size;
    }

    DIR *folder = opendir(path);

    struct dirent *element;
    size_t size = 4096;

    for (element = readdir(folder); element != NULL; element = readdir(folder)) {
        //(...)
        if (element->d_type == DT_DIR) {
            // Make sure the task receives a copy of the path
            char *priv_name = strdup(name); // (1)
            // recursive call of calculate_folder_size
            //               (2)
            #pragma omp task shared(size) firstprivate(priv_name)
            {
                // (3)
                #pragma omp atomic update
                size += calculate_folder_size(priv_name);
                free(priv_name); // (4)
            }
        } else {
            //(...)
        }
    }
    // (5)
    #pragma omp taskwait

    closedir(folder);
    return size;
}
```

The important parts here are:

1. You need to pass the task a name parameter that will live and retain its value until the task gets executed, which could be any time in the future. Therefore, you need to make a copy of `name`, e.g., using `strdup(3)`.
2. The task should remember the current value of `priv_name` since it will change during the next iteration of the loop. Therefore, the `firstprivate` treatment of `priv_name`. It also needs to be able to modify `size` in the parent context, hence `shared` for it.
3. Since all tasks are updating the same `size` variable in the parent scope, the access needs to be protected with `atomic update`.
4. The private name is no longer needed and must be disposed.
5. The parent task should wait for all child tasks to finish first before returning `size`.

This function must be called from within a parallel region in order to do its job in parallel:

```
int size;

#pragma omp parallel
#pragma omp single
size = calculate_folder_size("/some/path");
```

It might be a good idea to limit the depth of parallelism at which things still run in parallel. I leave it to you to figure it out how :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! This works well and your explanations really helped me.